# How do I extract records from a table which has datatype=Timestamp but I know only the date part of the key

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to retrieve records based on the coloumn having the datatype Timestamp

The block here is I don't know the exact timestamp, i want to fetch records with the same date .

to_date converts from timestamp to date .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for records between one day and the next. For example, if you want all records with the date of 1st January, you could do

```
SELECT
  field1,
  field2
FROM
  table
WHERE
  timestampField >= '2016-01-01'
  AND timestampField < '2016-01-02';
```